# Convolutional Neural Networks: Classes

Tags: database

Consider the output layer of a Convolutional Neural Network how many classes are there:

self.fc1=nn.Linear(out_2*49,5)

Answer (score 0):

Given below is the syntax of the nn.Linear object with **out_features** being size of the output sample. In your case since it's the output layer, **the number of output classes will be 5**.

```
torch.nn.Linear(in_features, out_features, bias=True, device=None, dtype=None)
```

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html